# Play framework 2.3.x Server Error Cannot register class

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3, stage, typesafe-activator

I recently uploaded Play application on server. Problem is that I can ran application through command **activator run** it compiles and runs fine. When I try to do **activator clean stage** it also compiles but after  **target/universal/stage/bin/name_of_myapp** it throws an error like

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot register class [models.Movie] in Ebean server]
at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743)
at play.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.java:310)
at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:81)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:244)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:280)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:275)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:275)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: models/Movie : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:79)
```

Java version on server is 1.7.x when mine is 1.8.0_31
I can't upgrade Java version on server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem resolved.
It was Java version on server being different than mine. After moving project to server I had to compile it with **./activator clean** later **./activator compile** so it was compiled under server Java. Now I am able to generate working stag and run it without error